# Sqlite select similar string matches

Tags: python, sqlite, difference

In other versions of `SQL` I have found the `DIFFERENCE` function so I could do a command like the following:

```
SELECT record_number WHERE DIFFERENCE(pers_name, "me") >= 0.9
```

I am using python, so I could iterate through using `difflib` but for large datasets, this would definitely not be practical. What can I use?

Comment: Write your own implementation of whatever this difference function does?

Comment: Sqlite doesn't actually care about the type of data stored, regardless of what you specify for each column. I _suspect_ this could be error-prone if it's implemented

Comment: Like I said, I could use `difflib` like: `difflib.SequenceMatcher (a = pers_name, b = "me").quick_ratio ()` but this could be slow for larger datasets. My question is, is there a way to do this (or something similar) in sqlite for fast implementation?